# Hide DIV within Iframe

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is it possible to hide a DIV within an Iframe if the source is some website not on your domain?
I have an iframe that loads a site but want to hide a specific div.

EX:
Hide DIV id = slider
src = www.somesitecom.com

What I have tried without success; Is is because a cross site scripting is not allowed?

```
$(function(){
        var f=$('#foo')
        f.load(function(){ 
            f.contents().find('#slider').hide(); 
        })
    })

<iframe id="foo" src="http://somesite.com" style="width:1200px; height:800; border:none; margin-left:-60px;"/></iframe>
```

Thanks,

Comment: This little fella comes in handy when dealing with iframes [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers do not allow `iframe` manipulations outside your domain for security reasons since you could get user confidential information in that page. For example, if that `iframe` is currently on a "Change profile" page, you could get really dangerous information.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think is there anyway to work around this issue?

Comment: Only if iframe is receptive to cross-origin communication using `window.postMessage` function but beware that not all browsers support it. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.postMessage

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. If you could manipulate other peoples pages so easily, you'd be able to access their databases or make phishing sites even easier.

You could make a solid colored div and overlay it with z-index to hide whatever is offending you, though.