# Hide Div on iFrame (Within same domain)

Tags: javascript, iframe

Okay so i'm pretty much trying to load a section from my forum onto my main page within an iframe.

I know it's not possible to manipulate frames that don't come from your own domain; but my forums on the same site so it should be sweet. 
When it loads; the iframe opens up the whole forum up; so I just want to hide certain divs on the loaded iframe.

I'm really not sure how I should go upon doing this.
I've tried many things like;

```
document.getElementById('page-header').style.display="none";
```

or

```
#page-header {
diplay: none;
}
```

But neither's seeming to work.

Any help would be great. (:

Comment: You should apply a class to `body` element, indicating that the page is being shown in a `iframe`. Then apply custom CSS rules for cases when the page is in an iframe. That is the best way.

Comment: @gskema that's incorrect. quoting from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe "An iframe is universally handled like a different HTML page by most browsers. If you want to apply the same stylesheet to the content of the iframe, just reference it from the pages used in there."

Comment: @Luca I dont think you understood what I meant

Comment: **To anyone going through the review queues:** This is not a duplicate of [Hide DIV within Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682782/hide-div-within-iframe). This question concerns manipulations within the *same domain*, whereas that question concerns manipulations for *a different domain*.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer on googles, thought i'd post it incase anyone else runs into this issue.

```
    $(function(){
        var f=$('#FRAMESID')
        f.load(function(){ 
            f.contents().find('#DIV_ID').hide(); 
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for Inner div of iframe.

```
$('#frame id').contents().find('#div Id').fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: that's jQuery - the OP didn't say they are using it

Comment: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Q_21501305.html

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

you first need to access your iframe, e.g. like this (supposing that you only have one iframe on your page):

```
  window.frames[0].document.getElementById('page-header').style.display="none";
```

read the documentation and find the way that best suits your existing code to find your iframe, but the code above should get you started